# Calculating $\arg(-1+\sqrt 3 \cdot i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> $$\arg(-1+\sqrt 3 \cdot i)$$

**My try:**

$$\arg=\arctan\bigg(\frac{\sqrt 3}{-1} \bigg)=-\frac{\pi}{3}$$

But the answer should be $\Large \frac{2 \pi}{3}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: @labbhattacharjee great, thanks

Comment: To get a sense of what's going on, it can be useful to plot your complex number $-1+\sqrt{3}i$ in the complex plane. Your argument $\theta$ is then the counter-clockwise angle from the positive $x$-axis, which should give you some trigonometric intuition as to what you need to do given the quadrant within which the complex number lies, e.g. $-1+\sqrt{3}i$ is in the second quadrant, so you you know it must be $\pi/2+\phi$ where $\phi$ can be computed using trigonometry and the complex diagram. Or you could compute it using $\pi-\phi'$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) for the definition of Arg$(z)$. In your case, let $z=x+iy$, with $x=-1$ and $y=\sqrt{3}$. Then $x<0$ and $y\geq0$, such that
$$\mathrm{Arg}(x+iy)=\mathrm{arctan}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\pi=-\frac{\pi}{3}+\pi=\frac{2}{3}\pi$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the point $(-1, \sqrt 3\  i)$ lies in the second quadrant of complex plane hence its argument is given as $$\arg=\pi-\tan^{-1}\left|\frac{\sqrt 3}{-1}\right|$$
$$=\pi-\tan^{-1}(\sqrt 3)$$$$=\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}=\color{red}{\frac{2\pi}{3}}$$

> **Edited:**
>   $$\color{red}{\arg(x+iy)}=\begin{cases} \color{blue}{\tan^{-1}\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|}\ \ \forall\ \  x>0, y>0\ \text{(point (x, y) lies in first quadrant)}\\
>  \color{blue}{\pi-\tan^{-1}\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|}\ \ \forall\ \  x<0, y>0\ \text{(point (x, y) lies in second quadrant)}\\
> \color{blue}{-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|}\ \ \forall\ \  x<0, y<0\ \text{(point (x, y) lies in third quadrant)}\\
> \color{blue}{-\tan^{-1}\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|}\ \ \forall\ \  x>0, y<0\ \text{(point (x, y) lies in fourth quadrant)}
> \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

The arctangent always yields results in the first and fourth quadrants. To find the other angle with the same tangent add half a circle. To decide which of the two solutions is the right one you need to look at the signs of the real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score -1):

Your attempt is right the change in answer is because the argument of a complex number is defined as the angle the complex number makes with positive x axis in anticlockwise direction so u should manipulate the answer and find the principle value of arctan of the $\mod(y/x)$  in the question . I hope my answer would be of some help